# Images not displayed for many Github sites (Content Security Policy)

Tags: github, content-security-policy

I experience a multitude of Github sites where the embedded images are not shown. By page inspection i get:

Examples:

[kafdrop](https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop/blob/master/README.md)

```
Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: github.githubassets.com identicons.github.com collector.githubapp.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com *.githubusercontent.com".
```

[Best README Template](https://github.com/othneildrew/Best-README-Template/blob/master/README.md)

```
Refused to load the image 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com.x.f7905b88047890475409fdb099cfa2fdcd23.9270fc5e.id.opendns.com/s/raw.githubusercontent.com/othneildrew/Best-README-Template/master/images/screenshot.png?X-OpenDNS-Session=_f7905b88047890475409fdb099cfa2fdcd239270fc5e_tzftKMMb_' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: github.githubassets.com identicons.github.com collector.githubapp.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com *.githubusercontent.com".
```

The following pages works fine:
[Vue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/README.md), [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/README.md), [FreeCodeCamp](https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/freeCodeCamp/blob/master/README.md).

Above is for Chrome, but same issue for Edge.
I *only* see these issues on my corporate PC (even outside the corporate VPN).

- Which security policies cause this? (Browser settings, firewall/antivirus?)
- Why are some pages failing why other are not?
- Does the failing sites actually cause a security risk (such as XSS), and should there be opened issues against the failing Github sites or Github in general?

Comment: Your corporate PC is misconfigured and you should report this misconfiguration to your IT department and insist that they fix it.  It is likely tampering with your data, and, in all likelihood, causing security problems.

Comment: I experienced this when using UrbanVPN Chrome extension. Even though no VPN was established.

Answer (score 3):

You are not loading your images from raw.githubusercontent.com but from raw.githubusercontent.com.x.f7905b88047890475409fdb099cfa2fdcd23.9270fc5e.id.opendns.com. It could be that your corporate PC does some rewrites to filter images through opendns.com. You would likely need to add "*.id.opendns.com" or "*.opendns.com" to img-src to work in this specific environment.

If you monitor CSP reports you will see that corporate security products often makes modifications that causes CSP violations.

Comment: *You would likely need to add opendns.com to img-src* - where is this done?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that, because this CSP is under Github authority.

Comment: Then you're stuck. For testing you could modify the header with a web proxy such as Fiddler. Otherwise need to modify usage of opendns in corporate enivroment.

Comment: Cisco is opendns.com (they acquired it). Cisco has confirmed to me, that this issue is in fact caused by `raw.githubusercontent.com` being proxied by Cisco Anyconnect Umbrella.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to verify that this does not violate any IT policies at your company but adding a line like
`185.199.108.133 raw.githubusercontent.com`

to "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" may fix it