# GitHub README Images Broken - "violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self'"

Tags: github, amazon-s3, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, broken-image

SO Community,

I use embedded images (icons, screenshots, etc.) in my GitHub repo READMEs and noticed today that all my images are now broken when they were previously working not that long ago (about a week or so). Some developer friends' repos are showing the same symptoms and browser console errors:

```
Refused to load the image 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com.x.912eb622002e804d2d0bc98027f64e5bb4af.9270fa5c.id.opendns.co
m/s/raw.githubusercontent.com/terrencemm2/terrencemm2/main/assets/japanese_flag.png?X-OpenDNS-
Session=_912eb622002e804d2d0bc98027f64e5bb4af9270fa5c_MHRsNPzb_' because it violates the 
following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: github.githubassets.com 
identicons.github.com collector.githubapp.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com 
*.githubusercontent.com".
```

**NOTE:** These are correct and display the correct image in a separate tab/window.

Typically, I've dedicated a separate, unmerged branch called `media` that contains any images I want to use in my README and then linked them like so ...

Option 1: `<img>` with full raw-content URL.
`<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/terrencemm2/terrencemm2/main/assets/azure.png" height=14 />`

Option 2: `<img>` with relative path.
`<img align="right" width="100" height="100" src="../media/logo.png?raw=true">`

Option 3: Image Markdown syntax per https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/.
`![Screenshot](../media/screenshot.png?raw=true)`

Comment: Where are you seeing these errors? Browser console? Embedded in the HTML? Elsewhere? Can you provide (or at least point to) a real example with the source text, the generated HTML and what the browser displays?

Comment: More specifically, my questions above are trying to narrow down whether the Content Security Policy which has been violated is GitHub's policy or your browser's policy.  Or maybe that is what you are asking. It's not clear as no questions exist in your "question."

Comment: @Waylan these errors are being shown in the browser console (Chrome). The code above is contained in my README.md files on GitHub. The browser displays a broken image icon.

Comment: I have this very same issue on virtually all MD pages at Github: "Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: github.githubassets.com identicons.github.com collector.githubapp.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com *.githubusercontent.com"." Meanwhile opening the image urls in a different tab works fine. What is befuddling is why it loads fine as a raw url but fails inline in the MD page? Latest example: https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect README

Comment: Thanks for your input @OskarAustegard.

UPDATE: I am on my company machine and VPN (thought to be one possible cause of the issue), and I can view all my embedded images in GitHub. Unfortunately, this is not an answer but the issue is resolved ... for now. 

Comment: See similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65699860/images-not-displayed-for-many-github-sites-content-security-policy
In my case, this is Cisco AnyConnect Umbrella causing a deep scan (TLS MITM) messing with the content.
I think because githubusercontent is classified as a "File sharing" category, which is rated "High": https://docs.umbrella.com/deployment-umbrella/docs/content-categories

Answer (score 3):

The domain you're using for this URL is incorrect.  Instead of `raw.githubusercontent.com`, you're trying to access the domain `raw.githubusercontent.com.x.912eb622002e804d2d0bc98027f64e5bb4af.9270fa5c.id.opendns.com`, and this is not allowed by GitHub's Content-Security-Policy header.

In all likelihood, you're on a network with a TLS man-in-the-middle device which is tampering with your data.  This is insecure, and your browser is correctly refusing to load data from that location, since GitHub's Content-Security-Policy doesn't allow loading that data.  You should disable this TLS tampering or contact your network administrator and inform them of this problem, asking them to promptly correct it.  Short of doing that, there is no way to solve this problem.

Comment: Hey, @bk2204. I am not attempting to access the content via the `.x.912...` address. I assume that is a redirect address based on the `raw.githubusercontent.com` that I have in my .md files.

I wouldn't put it past some type of filter/firewall on my device, so I will investigate that on my side.